# How to enact DRY to refrain from repeating code. NO concat please

Tags: javascript, dry, for-of-loop

I have 2 blocks of **'for'** code which are very similar with the exception for *Object.values(feelings)* and *Object.values(feelings2)* part.
I am trying to create a new 'const allFeelings' that holds the following code so as to enact DRY(Don't Repeat Yourself):

> ```
> tbody += '<tr>';
>   tbody += `<td class="menuItem">${menuItem}</td>`;
>   tbody += `<div class="hide description">${description}</div>`;
>   tbody += `<td>${value}</td>`;
>   tbody += '</tr>';
> ```

Please do NOT mistake this for concat as I have NO wish to concat these arrays. They are to remain separate.

```
    let tbody = '<tbody>';

for (const { menuItem, description, value } of Object.values(feelings)) {
    tbody += '<tr>';
    tbody += `<td class="menuItem">${menuItem}</td>`;
    tbody += `<div class="hide description">${description}</div>`;
    tbody += `<td>${value}</td>`;
    tbody += '</tr>';
}
for (const { menuItem, description, value } of Object.values(feelings2)) {
    tbody += '<tr>';
    tbody += `<td class="menuItem">${menuItem}</td>`;
    tbody += `<div class="hide description">${description}</div>`;
    tbody += `<td>${value}</td>`;
    tbody += '</tr>';
}

tbody += '</tbody>';
document.getElementById('tableData').innerHTML = tbody;
```

Comment: A most obvious solution without concat: pack both feelings into an array and make nested fors

Comment: `concat` returns a *new* array (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat) -- so what's the issue with combining them into `const allFeelings`?

Comment: As @jnpdx points out, `.concat()` does not mutate the arrays - so those will remain as-is when concat is used. Another way would be this: `for (const { menuItem, description, value } of [...Object.values(feelings), ...Object.values(feelings2)])`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a function.
For example,

```js
let tbody = '<tbody>';

function addToTableBody(feeling) {
  let returnVal = "";
  for (const {
      menuItem,
      description,
      value
    } of Object.values(feeling)) {
    returnVal += `
      <tr>
        <td class="menuItem">${menuItem}</td>
        <div class="hide description">${description}</div>
        <td>${value}</td>
      </tr>
    `
  }
  return returnVal;
}

tbody += addToTableBody(feelings)
tbody += addToTableBody(feelings2);

tbody += '</tbody>';
document.getElementById('tableData').innerHTML = tbody;
```

Answer (score 4):

`concat` doesn't mutate the existing array - it creates a new array. Creating such a combined array *just for the purposes of rendering* and not using it afterwards would seem to work. Your `feelings` and `feelings2` will remain separate.

Embedding everything inside a template literal will work well too.

```
const tbody = `
    <tbody>
        ${Object.values(feelings).concat(Object.values(feelings2)).map(({ menuItem, description, value }) => `
            <tr>
                <td class="menuItem">${menuItem}</td>
                <div class="hide description">${description}</div>
                <td>${value}</td>
            </tr>
        `)}
    </tbody>
`;
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. It was not quite what I was after but I appreciate the help.
I do not wish to combine these 2 arrays. When displayed on the DOM I want to keep them separate so I can implement flex-wrap : wrap on them.